# Python. Как удалить фигурные скобки при выводе значения словаря?

Tags: python, словарь

```
users_data_p = Path("users_data.json")
users_data = json.loads(users_data_p.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

users_data_list = list(users_data.items())
users_data_list.sort(key=lambda j: j[1].get('messages'))

for i in reversed(users_data_list):
    print(str(i[1]))
```

Выводит это:

```
{'messages': 145}
{'messages': 112}
{'messages': 90}
{'messages': 42}
```

Можно как-то убрать фигурные скобки и кавычки?

UPD:
Вот таким образом я смог убрать фигурные скобки, но кавычки остались

```
print(str(i[1])[1:-1].format())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
users_data_list = [
    [1, {'messages': 42}],
    [2, {'messages': 90}],
    [3, {'messages': 112}],
    [4, {'messages': 145}],
]

for i in reversed(users_data_list):
    k, v = list(i[1].items())[0]
    print(f'{k}: {v:>3}')
```

Comment: значения в 'messages' постоянно изменяются, так что переопределить словарь я не могу

Comment: `print(str(i[1])[1:-1].format())` Вот таким образом я смог убрать фигурные скобки, но кавычки остались

Comment: @ynx1 я не совсем понимаю что вы пишите,  покажите что у вас в `users_data_list`

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы выводите какой-то объект через функцию `print` или вызываете функцию `str(object)`, то на они в своей реализации обращаются к методу `__str__` данного объекта.
В данном случае `i[1]` - это словарь, который стандартно выводится как `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`.

Для того, чтобы вывести словарь в удобном для вас виде, нужно пройти в цикле по всем его парам ключ-значение, либо обратиться к конкретным значениям по их ключам. Поскольку у вас словарь состоит всегда из одного элемента, это можно реализовать и без цикла, например, так:

```
for i in reversed(users_data_list):
    k, v = list(i[1].items())[0]
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать свой словарь, чтобы не писать каждый раз цикл:

```
In [4]: class ReprDict(dict):
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return "\n".join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in self.items())
   ...:

In [5]: d = ReprDict({1: 2, "hello": "world"})

In [6]: d
Out[6]:
1: 2
hello: world

In [7]: print(d)
1: 2
hello: world
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

for i in reversed(users_data_list):

```
  for key in i[1]:

    print(i[0], '->', key, ':', i[1].get(key))
```